# How do i resolve pyPDF2 import error on pythonanywhere

Tags: pypdf, pythonanywhere

on pythonanywhere bash console, I installed pyPDF2 using pip install. when I run the app,
always getting error at below line:
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
**error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyPdf2 **
Need help to resolve this...thanks

I tried installing pypdf and using that package. doesnt work either.

Comment: Make sure you run your app with the same Python version / virtual environment you installed to package to and/or you reloaded the web app after installing the package.  I couldn't reproduce the behavior you described, so once the package is properly installed, the import should work.